# Trying to extend a class, while onseekbarchangelistener is implemented?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 3 classes i am working with, a drawing view which sits inside of the drawing box and a tools button. My tools button has the seekbar and listener for the size change of my stroke, the stroke is in the canvasview class, i am trying to extend my canvas view with the tools class but i have the

```
public class Toolbox extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
```

when i try to add the extends canvasview i get an error. How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: what's the error you are getting? did you implement all the abstract methods?

Comment: are you trying to extend canvasview in Toolbox class then you can't extend more the one class in java

Comment: Ok i see i cant extend more than one class now, ty for the info! Heres where i am at. My tools button opens a layout inflator with the tools class in it, it has my seekbar and seek listener, when i use the seekbar i want it to change the size of stroke i use for drawing. The stroke is in the canvasview class though, when i try to reference it in the tools class the variable isnt found.. How then do i call for this variable to be tied to my seekbar?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in `implements OnSeekBarChangeListener`, but in extending `Canvas`. You can extend only one class in Java. `Toolbox` already extends `AppCompatActivity`.